# WebPack loader generates SVG sprite file without CSS file

Tags: svg, webpack, gulp, sprite

I used gulp-svg-sprites to convert multiple SVGs into a single large Sprites, and besides generating symbols and appropriate css selectors in a file.

For architecture change purpose, I am migrating all gulp processes on Webpack 3. The last thing I can't achieve to reproduce with Webpack is the SVG Sprite generation.

#### Using Gulp-svg-sprites, the script was:

```
var thisPipe = gulpSrc(svgSrc)
    .pipe(svgSprite(config.svgSprites.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(svgDest));
```

where compilerOptions represents the options available with svgSprite.

I tried several approaches, but I hardly suspect I'm doing something wrong (or misusing the tools I tried).

I mainly looked at https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader/, with a simple use case :

- `./img/icons/icon-1.svg` has to be moved to `./build/img/sprints.svg`
- A CSS file must be created in order to use icons in the sprite file.
- The folder "./img/icons" can contains a lot of svgs.

About part 1 (SVG sprites generation) of my `webpack.config.ts` file about svg is :

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
            options: {
                extract: true,
                spriteFilename: 'sprite.svg'
            }
        }, {...}] ...
```

I did not specify specific "entry" or "output" neither did I not use `ExtractTextPlugin` on svg files.

About part 2 (CSS file), I have no clue about how to generate the CSS file from that.

---

1. How can I generate a Sprite file using Webpack ?
2. How can I generate the "twin" CSS file ?

Thank you.

Comment: I gave up finding a WebPack solution and oriented myself to https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-sprite.
That allowed me to removed my Gulp stack. 
Gulp-svg-sprites actually encapsulated svg-sprite, and that's why I was easily able to re-use the previous config with svg-sprite, leading to a quick success.